# Using Spring AOP 3.1.0 to set service instance using method argument

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

Hi i am new to Annotation and Spring AOP. below is what i am trying to achieve

```
public interface Service {
    public void process(String ServiceName, Bean bean);
}

public class ServiceImpl1 implements Service{
    public void process(String ServiceName, Bean bean) {

        /// do something here    
    }
}

public class ServiceImpl2 implements Service{
    public void process(String ServiceName, Bean bean) {

        /// do something here
    }
}
```

from other class i would be calling something like

```
...

public void doSomething(String serviceName, Bean bean){

    service.process("ServiceImpl1", bean); 

}
...
```

I can achieve the same by using AroundAdvice and Before advice and intercepting my doSomething method  and then instantiate the service object after reading the serviceName.

I there is a better approach for this?

I just need a direction and then i will figure this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am guessing what you want to do is have a Before advice that takes the passed in service name, creates an object of appropriate class, then calls the appropriate method on that newly created object.  It seems like, to me, you are really looking for more of a Factory pattern, but trying to use AOP to accomplish it.

If you took the Factory pattern, you would create a class called ServiceFactory, which takes some parameters and returns the correct Service implementation for those parameters.  You calling code would simply use the Factory to get the right Service at runtime.

Another approach, if you want to stick with more of a DI pattern, might be to create a wrapper class that serves as the "conductor".  This might have a Map of service names to Service implementation.  You could then inject this wrapper into your code, and even inject the Map into the wrapper.  Your calling code would call methods on the wrapper, which would locate the correct, singleton implementation and aggrigate the call to it.

I just feel that using AOP for this is asking for trouble.

Comment: yes i am trying to achieve this with AOP. I already have a Factory pattern in place.

Comment: I don't know, this just seems like it should be in a book of anti-patterns.  In your scenario, you could create and instance of ServiceImpl1, but using AOP end up calling a method on ServiceImpl2.  Not to mention, the selection is based on some arbitrary String passed into the method.  All sorts of alarms are going off in my head.  Not only does this seem to be not-so-very secure, but I couldn't imagine trying to support this at all.  Any, what is it really buying you that more well-established patterns don't?

Comment: As i have already mentioned i am looking for a better approach if this is not the one, I already have factory implementation in place. If there is a clearer approach with annotation then why not? if this is not secure, can you explain why this is not?

Comment: Well, my first thought is that someone could write a custom Service implementation, put it in the classpath, and call it using this code.  You are basically writing a "plugin" mechinism, but since your service names appear to be hard-coded to the classnams, I am not sure what you are getting by doing this.  If you want a different approach, and want to stay true to Spring, then I would suggest DI.  I have done things where I load different config files based on JVM arguments/System variables/properties so that I can load one thing for DEV, another for TEST, and something else for Prod.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the service impl class using the spring @Autowire annotation. Since u have 2 implementation classes, you can use qualifier to specify which impl needs to b injected.